# Android - View too large to fit into drawing cache

Tags: android, caching, canvas, view

I have a class that extends custom view, it has to draw a line and some text like a timeline. 
It can be pretty long so I put the view into a scrollview.

It works fine but if the line is too long the view disappears and become invisible (the ScrollView scrolls) and Logcat shows me this message:

```
07-02 15:56:05.209: W/View(7364): View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 4392400 bytes, only 4096000 available
```

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solved this problem because I am also having the exact same problem.

Comment: Actually adding 'android:hardwareAccelerated="false" '  to manifest solves the problem but it hinders the performance greatly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to increase RAM, perhaps you can draw less. Remove `ScrollView`, detect touch on View, draw only visible portion.

Comment: The problem is that on bottom of the view I have some widgets to show, so I need scrollview